# How do I transfer an array from one class to another, specifically the int field in the source class array

Tags: java, arrays, object, cloneable

I implemented compareTo in my Student class which implements Comparable  which has a private int age field. I also have a Classroom class which has a classroom array that takes in Student objects. I have my classroom array and I want to send it's individual int age fields into a new Student array. How would I do that because referencing doesn't work with array indexes in a for loop for example:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < classroom.getSize(); i++)
        {
            studentArray[i] = classroom[i].getAge();
        }
```

Assuming my getters are correct and and arrays are declared properly, this declaration doesn't work because it's two different types of objects. What are the alternatives?

Comment: Please post a MCVE. I can't tell what you're asking. Your code doesn't use `compareTo`.

Comment: It's an override method I wrote in student class and it's not needed for what i'm doing. I did it to have Student implement comparable and use Arrays.sort()

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It's pretty clear why your code doesn't work, but it's not clear at all what you're trying to do.

Comment: As far as I have understood your problem, you want to set `Integer` from one class to another. You can call the `setAge()` method for student class. You can do something like this: `studentArray[i].setAge(classroom[i].getAge());`